# Is string.GetHashCode() sufficent for word dictionaries in nlp?

Tags: c#, nlp

can I use the `string.GetHashCode()` function for storing stemming data reliably?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use string.GetHashCode to balance a hash table. That's all it is designed to be used for, and that's all it should be used for.

In particular, the documentation specifically states that you should under no circumstances persist hashcodes to permanent storage; the string hash code algorithm is permitted to change at any time, and in fact has done so in the past.

Comment: The algorithm may also return wildly different results on different machines when used this way.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN at [Object.GetHashCode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

> The default implementation of the
>   GetHashCode method does not guarantee
>   unique return values for different
>   objects. Furthermore, the .NET
>   Framework does not guarantee the
>   default implementation of the
>   GetHashCode method, and the value it
>   returns will be the same between
>   different versions of the .NET
>   Framework. Consequently, the default
>   implementation of this method must not
>   be used as a unique object identifier
>   for hashing purposes.